# Date().getTimezoneOffset() in Javascript vs TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes in .net server side

Tags: javascript, .net, timezone-offset

I have a javascript function used in my application

```
Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

I need server side function to replace the same. I am using

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes;
```

Is there any difference between the two, other than -ve and +ve value? Can I use this server side method in place of this javascript function.

Comment: What  serverside language?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mozilla Developer Docs for JavaScript states,

> The **getTimezoneOffset()** method returns the time zone difference, in
>   minutes, from current locale (host system settings) to UTC.

The method summary comments for **GetUtcOffset** in .NET describes

> **Summary:**
>
> Calculates the offset or difference between the time in this time zone and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) for a particular date and time.

Essentially both do almost the same job, except the .Net returns a **TimeSpan** object whereas the JavaScript's is just a number (the offset difference in minutes)

The TotalMinutes property value in the TimeSpan object infact returns the same value as JavaScripts'

Answer (score 0):

They are the same except the sign (+/-), but keep in mind:

- They both return the *current* local offset.  The offset for some other point in time in the same time zone may be different.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- "Local" means local to where the code is executing.  So in a web application, the server-side code is using the time zone setting of the server.  It has no idea about the time zone of your user.